# .NET Charting Controls: Label values from data source

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-chart-controls

I know that you can use keywords with labels, but is there any way to use a specific value from my data set as a label? What I would like to do is have a column of my data table contain a custom label string, so that each X-axis value graphed would have a unique label, but it seems there is no way to connect a series to an element from my data source. Is there a workaround to this, or will I just have to manually add labels over the chart?

Comment: Did you try setting `VALX` as the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for setting a label for your datasource which is different from the columns which derive the X and Y values.In that case you can do this in the following manner

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(data, "XValue", "YValue", 
                               "ToolTip=mytooltip,Label=LabelColumnName");
```

Here you can specify the column name against Label which would be used to display the label, in the same fashion you could also set up the tooltip from a different property.

If this is not you are looking out then please update the question with more details.

**EDIT**

you can set the position of the label using CustomProperties of the series

`Chart1.Series[0].CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Left";` [Check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489245.aspx)

Comment: Also, is there anyway to control the positioning of the label? Some of my labels are overlapping and I would like to either change the alignment(left, right, center), or be able to specify an offset as a number of pixels?